# How to load json array

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im trying to load person data from api : www.swapi.co .
However i dont know how can i load movies titles 
instead of their api adress.

```
$(function(){

var list = $('.list');
var submit = $('.submit-people');
var people = '1';

submit.on('click',function(){
    people++;
    list.empty();

    $.ajax({

        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://swapi.co/api/people/' + people + '/',

        success: function(data) {

            list.append('<li>Name:' + data.name + '</li>');
            list.append('<li>Height:' + data.height + '</li>');
            list.append('<li>Mass:' + data.mass + '</li>');
            list.append('<li>Gender:' + data.gender + '</li>');
            list.append('<li>Movies:' + data.films + '</li>');

        }

    })

})
```

my current code is here : https://jsfiddle.net/wtpy71d7/2/

really thanks for any help or suggestions

Comment: For each of the films in `data.films`, you have to do another query (another `$.ajax`) to fetch the details (e.g., movie title). This is a common feature of REST APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you.

```
success: function(data) {
     ...
     for(var i = 0; i< data.films.length; i++ )
          $.ajax({
             type: "get",
             url: data.films[i],

             success: function (data) {
                list.append('<li>Movies:' + data.title + '</li>');
             }
          });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are giving you the URL for another API Request.
What you could do is make another AJAX call and get each movie details, then parse those results and append them to your list. It could look something like this.

```
list.append('<li>Movies:' + getMovies(data.films) + '</li>');
```

Your next ajax call might look something like this:

```
var getMovies = function(moviesAPI) {

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: moviesAPI,
  success: function(data) {
  return data;
  }
})

}
```